# Change width of an element with scrolling window

Tags: scroll, width

i use this code to change width of a div only one time, when i'm scrolling page bigger or smaller than a specified measure . but it's not working properly .it work with a many time delay . someone can help me?
Thank you .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var a = $(this).scrollTop(),
            b = 50; //minimum top scroll amount//
        if (a > b){
            $('div').animate({'width':'100%'});
        }else{
            $('div').animate({'width':200});
        };
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7tmo48mo/

Comment: What does it do instead of working?

Comment: can you put this code into a jsfiddle?

Comment: ok. i put it in jsfiddle.